# Accessing contract functions from web3 and javascript

Tags: web3js, contract-design, contract-invocation, ganache, web3js-v1.x

I have deployed a contract in a private blockchain using remix and ganache. Now I want to interact with it trough web3 and the console from my browser, but I'm not managing to interact with the contract functions in the browser. This in my index.html:

index.html

```
var simpleStorageAbi =
    [
        {
            "constant": false,
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "getValue",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": false,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "val",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "setValue",
            "outputs": [],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "inputs": [],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "constructor"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "value",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        }
    ];

var SimpleStorageContract = new web3.eth.Contract(simpleStorageAbi);
var simpleStorageInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(simpleStorageAbi, "(address)");
```

When I open the console from the browser the contract I type:

```
simpleStorageInstance
```

and I would expect the contract functions:

```
{…}
> getValue
> setValue
> value
```

instead I get this

```
Contract {_requestManager: RequestManager, givenProvider: null, providers: {…}, setProvider: ƒ, …}
BatchRequest: ƒ ()
clearSubscriptions: ƒ (keepIsSyncing)
currentProvider: (...)
defaultAccount: (...)
defaultBlock: (...)
defaultChain: (...)
defaultCommon: (...)
defaultHardfork: (...)
events: {allEvents: ƒ}
extend: ƒ ex(extension)
givenProvider: null
handleRevert: (...)
methods: {getValue: ƒ, 0x20965255: ƒ, getValue(): ƒ, setValue: ƒ, 0x} etc
```

I tried accessing the functions in this way

```
simpleStorageInstance.methods.setValue(5);
```

but I get nothing in return (no transaction returned).

```
{arguments: Array(1), call: ƒ, send: ƒ, encodeABI: ƒ, estimateGas: ƒ, …}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think there is a possibility that you don't have the correct web3 provider. Can you please include your code where you got connected to ganache?

Comment: The connection to ganache was fine, it was the call function that was incomplete!

Answer (score 1):

Made it work, a piece of code was missing after the methods call.

Here the complete call function from the browser console:

```
simpleStorageInstance.methods.setValue(5).send({from: '(address)', gas: 3000000});
```

This sends the transaction that can be seen in ganache.